# detect Ray cast without having Collider on Game Object

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

so I'm trying to detect  an object without having collider on that object but unfortunately I'm stuck   on it ;

Comment: Why is a collider so bad?

Comment: I would use geometry and check if a line intersects withe plane of interest. You can probably use the `Ray` and `Plane` unity classes for that. Much better and directly with raycast + collider though

Answer (score 3):

With the exception of a graphics raycast for UI elements on a canvas and possibly [Plane.Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.Raycast.html) which is specific to planes, Unity Raycasts hit colliders and nothing else. If you want an object to be hit by raycasts you need to add a collider.